# Inserting line break in page names used in CSS list menu in Kentco 9

Tags: css, nav, kentico

I've created a menu in Kentico 9 using the "CSS list menu" web part. I've styled it using CSS and all was well until I added a new Page menu item. Now the items no longer fit on a single line in the nav. Because the lengths of the Document Names are uneven, ideally I'd like to simply add a line break around the ampersand of the longer titles. (I haven't found a way to insert a line break based on a specific character using CSS)

Dividing the width evenly between each `<li>` element via a percentage pushes the first title into three lines, leaves large gaps between menu items and looks unattractive. Something to keep in mind is the hover function that reveals each parent page's first level child pages below it.

Current menu appearance:

[image: Current menu appearance]

I haven't made any significant changes to the web part and "word wrap" is checked. Here is the CSS code:

```css
/* Horizontal menu - main menu */

header nav {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; /* Container width is 960px */
  background-color: rgb(1, 69, 106);  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding:0;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}

header nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 10px solid rgb(1, 69, 106);
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li a:visited {
  color: rgb(234, 161, 23);
}

header nav ul li a:hover,
header nav ul li a:active,
header nav ul li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
  background-color: rgb(8, 96, 143);
  border: 10px solid rgb(8, 96, 143);
}

header nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

header nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(1, 69, 106);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

header nav ul li ul li {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgb(1, 69, 106);
}

header nav ul li ul li a {
  border: 5px solid rgb(1, 69, 106);
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li ul li a:hover,
header nav ul li ul li a:active,
header nav ul li ul li a:focus {
  border: 5px solid rgb(8, 96, 143);
}

header nav ul ul ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class or styles to each page under page properties -> navigation - this means each page could have different class in top navigation. Having this in place you can explicitly specify width for each menu item and add word wrap:

```
.myNavItem1 {
  white-space: normal;
  width: 80px;
}
```

Another approach is using drop down menu - it renders as table, so it never shifts items to the next line, but I personally do not like tables as they do not provide enough flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the RenderedHTML property if nothing else helps: http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/9_0/api/html/P_CMS_Controls_CMSListMenu_RenderedHTML.htm